# how to make eclipse recognize my device for debugging?

Tags: android, eclipse

I write an android app using eclipse.

I have plugged in my new device (not rooted)

and I try to install my app on the device.

Unfortunately, eclipse shows the device is "unknown"

how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you install Android ADB driver for that device type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First of all, be sure your device has USB debugging set. This is in Settings => developer options.*

*If you can not access Android developer options, Go on Settings, About phone, and click 7 times on Build Number*

Sometimes, Eclipse won't recognize device if you plug it in while Eclipse is open. 2 solution

1. Go in DDMS console, and in the Devices window, click on "View Menu" (arrow going down at the right), then reset ADB. It should freeze eclipse for few seconds, then your device will be recognized.

   View Menu button is here

   [image]
2. Restart Eclipse

Comment: gunare asked me `Did you install Android ADB driver for that device type? ` is this needed? how do i do this?